# Realm React Native - How to update multiple objects in a loop

Tags: react-native, realm

I am trying to update multiple object in realm react native using for loop like this:

```
let pendingReadings = database.objects('Readings').filtered('synced = false');
database.write(() => {
    for (var k=0;k<pendingReadings.length;k++) {
        pendingReadings[k].synced = true;
    }
});
```

The result should mark all readings synced true. However, it only marks alternative objects as synced (Maybe the previous write isn't complete when the request for next one comes in). What is the best way to update all entries in one go?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Realm's query results are live-updating. There are various way you could adjust your loop to account for that, but you would get the best performance by using the [`snapshot()`](https://realm.io/docs/react-native/latest/api/Realm.Results.html#snapshot) method on results instead...

```
let pendingReadings = database.objects('Readings')
                              .filtered('synced = false')
                              .snapshot();
database.write(() => {
    for (let i = 0, len = pendingReadings.length; i < len; i++) {
        pendingReadings[i].synced = true;
    }
});
```

Also notice I adjusted the loop to only retrieve the `length` once, which would slightly improve performance as well. You could use `for...of` loops with Realm collections if you'd like, though there is a slight performance penalty in doing so compared to a "raw" loop like the one above.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. But my question really is that all objects in this loop aren't synced. why is that happening? Thanks for letting me know about the snapshot method. I was about to look for something like this.

Comment: Because the query results are live-updating and filtering on `synced = false`, when you set the first one to `true` (`pendingReadings[0].synced = true`), it is removed from the query results and the items are shifted down (second one become the first, etc.). That is why you're seeing every other item get set to `true`. Using the `snapshot()` will avoid that unwanted live-updating behavior in this case.

Comment: Thanks alot for the explanation. Worked great!

Answer (score 0):

> pendingReadings.update('synced', true)